# Creating a subset in R using a double loop

Tags: r, loops, double, conditional-statements, subset

I have a very large csv file I have imported into R and need to make a subset of data.
The csv looks something like this:

```
Julian_Day   Id   Year
52            1   1901
56            5   1901
200           1   1968
```

ect, where year is `1901-2010`, Id `1-58` and Julian_Day `1-200` for about `130,000` rows of data. So I only want the lowest Julian Day value for each year for each Id and to get rid of all other rows of data.

Comment: This is a very basic thing to do. Have you read the [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply with base R

```
aggregate(Julian_Day ~., df, min)
#   Year Id Julian_Day
# 1 1901  1         40
# 2 1968  1        200
# 3 1901  5         56
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Id, Year) %>%
  summarise(Julian_Day = min(Julian_Day))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: Id
# 
#   Id Year Julian_Day
# 1  1 1901         40
# 2  1 1968        200
# 3  5 1901         56
```

Comment: it's saying: "Error in UseMethod ("group_by_"): no applicable method for 'group by' applied to an object of class function

Comment: You''ll have to provide your data set. Otherwise i can't reproduce your error. I used the data provided by Colonel

Answer (score 2):

**Data**:

```
df = data.frame(Year=c(1901,1901,1968,1901),
                Id=c(1,5,1,1),
                Julian_Day=c(52,56,200,40),
                Animal=c('dog','doggy','style','fashion'))
```

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ ,min:=min(Julian_Day), by=list(Id, Year)]
#>df
#   Year Id Julian_Day  Animal min
#1: 1901  1         52     dog  40
#2: 1901  5         56   doggy  56
#3: 1968  1        200   style 200
#4: 1901  1         40 fashion  40
```

Comment: Alright so I tried that, the only problem is that I left out that there are more columns for each row. Essentially each row is an observation of an animal, with the date, latitude, longitude, location ect so I want all of the information in that row to come along so I can bring it back into excel. I'm really just trying to eliminate all the rows of data that are not the first sighting of the animal (Id) for each year.

Comment: edited. Is it what you want?

Comment: Id is the animal (species). I gave each species a number to make it easier, at least i thought it would but yes, plus there's the latitude, longitude, city, human footprint ect, butI just want those values to stay with the first sighting.

Comment: you ask a question, you have 3 differents answers working. And then you speak about data format completely different. Either you open a new question, either you adapt these answers to your problem, which is just replacing the dummy variable names with your real variable names ;)

Comment: When I did it your suggested way, it worked by telling me the lowest Julian Day for each Id for each year however it didn't show all the additional information for the rows (lat, long, city ect). Is that a subset you made? That could be imported back to excel?

Comment: I added the variable animal to show you how to conserve all original data and simply adding the minimum ....Yes you can export in `csv`. See `write.table` function.

Comment: I've never used this site before but if I still have questions here I can't ask them here, I need to open another question again?

Comment: Yes, you need to open another topic for a different question. For slight change you can always alter your initial question. If an answer satisfies the inital request you generally accept it, this closes the topic.

Comment: My guess the OP is looking for `setDT(df)[ ,.SD[which.min(Julian_Day)], .(Id, Year)]`